# Server power meter, 220V

Tags: electrical-power

I would like to monitor my server power usage over time, but I'm in 220V area (Europe), and everything I can find on the net is for 110V, like this one here:

[Kill A Watt Load Meter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16882715001&cm_re=load_meter-_-82-715-001-_-Product)

It seems like everything I can find is fitted with UK plugs, and I live in Croatia - any info about such device - affordable price range is around $20.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found one in Croatia.  Here it is:

http://www.chipoteka.hr/artikl/6071050021

Answer (score 2):

APC do a range of metered power strips which might be what you are after, the company i work for have a couple and we have them setup in monitoring to check how much power we are using and also to alert us if we go over a certain threshold.

But if you are only after monitoring a single server this will most probably be a little over kill. If your in the UK i know Maplins sell them otherwise i would say go take a look at Farnell they normally have outlets all over Europe

http://uk.farnell.com/pro-elec/2000mu/monitor-power-energy/dp/1305710

Answer (score 2):

This looks very similar (although less expensive) to my Kill A Watt, only with the outlet you'll need: [Plug-In Energy Consumption Monitor](http://www.homeenergysaving.co.uk/plugin-electricity-consumption-monitor.html)

From the page:

Ideal to find the electricity consumption and running costs of: 
   - Fridges and Freezers 
   - Computers and all associated peripherals 
   - Standby Costs of TV, DVD, computer, stereo, video, chargers etc 
   - Washing Machines - Find the cost of your 30, 40, 60 degree wash 
   - Dehumidifiers & Air Con units 
   - Pond pumps, Swimming pool pumps (if they have a plug) 
   - Televisions - CRT, LCD or Plasma 
   - Anything that plugs into a wall socket !

Simply plug this monitor into the wall then plug the item into the monitor and you'll see exactly how much electricity it consumes. Once you have this figure it's easy to work out the running cost.

Comment: The particular feature of this model I like the best (and which is available in my Kill A Watt) is running in KWH mode that keeps a running tally of energy consumption in kilowatt hours since the last press of the reset button. This allows you to calculate the energy consumption of a device (or devices) over a period of time. Essentially allowing you to figure out the costs on an annual basis.

Comment: And yet it's not what OP asked for: the item you linked has UK style plugs, whereas he (and me too) needs continental style plugs.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [HERE](http://www.amazon.co.uk/s?ie=UTF8&search-type=ss&index=electronics-uk&field-keywords=Power%20Accessories) - these are fitted with UK plugs but you could just use a converter plug or see if they have a Croatian-pinned version.